# How to find files executed after a respring / restart?

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Whenever, I respring or restart my iPad, three ugly spam icons appear on my device. I tried to uninstall them. However, they keep reappearing after each restart. I found that they were installed by a **"Facebook Ads Blocker"** jailbreak tweak from **"Bovor.net/ios"** source.

How can I find the script that creates these spam icons?

How can I download the .deb file and extract it to see where the spam is being created?

Comment: Bro, I have been looking for answers, for hours. It is 09:04 am in Iraq and I have not slept a second this whole night trying to solve this. Funny that you have said that "does not show any research effort" :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to grab and extract the .deb file and its content was not related to ugly icons. However, it revealed that this package "Facebook Ads Blocker" had a dependency. I went to cydia and removed the dependency and Horraaaay!!! the spam icons were removed :)